# Do I have to call DataObject.RemovePastingHandler()?

Tags: c#, wpf

My program has a custom user control that includes a pasting handler.  Is it necessary to call the `DataObject.RemovePastingHandler` method at any point, or will my handler be cleaned up by the framework, e.g. when the object is Garbage Collected?

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
        : base()
    {
        // Other construction & initialisation code goes here.

        // Add the pasting handler.
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(this, PastingHandler);

        // Do I need to call the complimentary method anywhere?
        // DataObject.RemovePastingHandler(this, PastingHandler);
    }

    private static void PastingHandler(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do magic to handle the paste request.
    }
}
```